# Hadoop reduce jobs completed successfully but processes remains and taking memory

Tags: hadoop

There is a 4 node hadoop cluster. One of the main node have a strange bug that is the reduce processes finished the job, but it did not terminate. It makes the memory exceed quickly.

I don't know what cause this problem but it only occurs on one node, others are fine. There is also no any error report of the job, just a processes doing nothing.

Comment: @climbage it is 1.2.1

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem was. I used a library that would open multi-thread when heavy load. If the threads never stop, the processes remains running either.